# Add horizontal line at certain height of a dynamic div

Tags: html, css

I have a div which the height is about 2300px, i want to add a separate line at height=900px like a A4 paper, but as the content of the div can be different, i don't know  how to add it(after which sub div element) in the html file, can you tell me how to add this line automaticaly with css, please?
Thank you.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Angular or Javascript, I have removed the corresponding tags.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create another div and place that on top of your content.

```css
.content {
  height: 2300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
}

.border {
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid white;
  position: relative;
  top: 900px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>DYNAMIC CONTENT HERE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="border"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a div inside your div with the height of 900px and add a border-bottom.